# Music Player with Web Remote

Tags: linux, music, web, media-player, remote-access

I recently found the plugin for Rhythmbox (the standard music player shipped with Ubuntu) which lets you control the playback from any other device in the network via a web interface. Unfortunately this web interface is very limited: It only allows to play/pause and move to the previous or next track.

Is there another music player that has a web interface that lets you control more things?

For example I'd really like to have the overview that lets you choose an artist or an album directly, without having to click through hundreds of tracks.

Answer (score 2):

The VLC player supports also a web interace.
Please check out:

- https://wiki.videolan.org/Control_VLC_via_a_browser/
- https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Modules/http_intf/

Comment: Standard web-interface has also some limitations. If you run web-app on mobile you cannot clear the playlist. There are some iOS/Android apps that use RPC and can control VLC in a convenient way. They are not for free.

Answer (score 1):

Like said above: **Clementine** for just music

if you wish the same to happen with video's maybe try **VLC** or **Kodi**.

**Kodi** also ships a app that will allow you to use your Android or iPhone as a remote.

Comment: Kodi is not good for always-ON devices, as it drains CPU even in the idle state. I use it on my R-Pi and I stuck at version v15.x. This version consumes ~2-5% in the idle. Version v16.x uses ~20% of CPU.

Answer (score 1):

There is another music player backend called [Music Player Daemon (MPD)](https://www.musicpd.org/). You can find binaries for Windows and Linux. There is a Web interface, however I did not try it. Instead I used iPhone to control the daemon.

I've managed to install MPD on the ASUS Tinker Board powered with Armbian and control it with [MPD Pilot](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/mpd-pilot/id1536331909) iPhone app.

The installation was easy:

1. Install mpd with `apt install mpd sonata`. See instruction [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MPD).
2. Create symlinks in the `/var/lib/mpd/music/` folder
3. Disable ALSA output to force MPD to use default sound output (/etc/mpd.conf)
4. Delete `/var/lib/mpd/tag_cache` and restart `mpd` daemon

I'm not sure about step 3 though.

Then find the app you like on the Google Play/Appstore and connect to <ip_address>:6600.

The related questions:

- [Controlling music player from web (on superuser.com)](https://superuser.com/questions/138574/controlling-music-player-from-web)

Answer (score 0):

## [Clementine](https://www.clementine-player.org/de/)

- can be controlled via Android app.
- It exists a 3rd-party [web interface](https://github.com/tjofle/clementine-webremote), but it hasn't been updated in a while.

Android app:

- [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/de.qspool.clementineremote/)
- [Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.qspool.clementineremote&hl=en)